# jQuery UI resizable showing handler much below the textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jQuery UI's resizable method to resize a textarea. The code that I have used is :-

```
  $(function() {
  $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  });
```

This is the basic syntax. But the resize handler appear much below the textarea. You can see my output at http://jsfiddle.net/cMX4q/1/. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding this css:

```
.ui-resizable-handle {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 0.1px;
       display: block;
       margin: 15px 5px;
 }
```

[**Demo Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cMX4q/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in CSS,

`.ui-wrapper { padding-bottom:0; padding-right:0;}`

OR

You can get the same result in jQuery

`$( "#resizable" ).resizable().parent().css('padding','0');`